# Inconsistency when using SysV semaphores

Tags: c, synchronization, fork, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm trying to apply my theoretical knowledge of semaphores using SysV semaphores and shared memory APIs.

Well briefly, I'm sharing an `int`-sized memory (which is guarded by a semaphore) between 50 processes, each one increments it 1000 times, so ultimately i must have a final value of `1000 * 50 = 50000` but weirdly I'm having values like : 49962, 49965, 49366...

Here is my c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#define SHMSZ sizeof(int) /* Size of an integer*/

int main(){
    key_t key = 241096; /* Hard-coded key */
    int shm_id, sem_id, *shm;
    struct sembuf psem = {0, -1, 0};
    struct sembuf vsem = {0, 1, 0};

    if((shm_id = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1){
        printf("Err shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((shm = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == (int *) -1){
        printf("Err shmat");
    }

    *shm = 0; /*Initilize the shared memory*/

    if((sem_id = semget(key, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1){
        printf("Err semget prg");
        exit(1);
    }

    /***Semaphore initialization****/
    semop(sem_id, &vsem, 1); /*set sem_value to 1*/
    /**********************************/

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0){
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
                semop(sem_id, &psem, 1); /*wait for the semaphore*/
                *shm = *shm + 1;
                semop(sem_id, &vsem, 1); /* signal the semaphore*/
            }
            return 0; /*Whene done incrementing, return */
        }
    }
    while((wait(NULL) != -1)); /*Wait for all children to terminate*/
    printf("--%i--", *shm); /*Print the final value of the shared  memory*/
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried executing your code, it is printing 50000 as expected. 
Try to use ftok with the key to generate a non-redundant key between two different shared memories.

```
key_t key = ftok(FileName, AnyChar); // The program must have the right to access the file.
```

If you get these values when executing multiple times your executable, it's certainly because you didn't use ipcrm -a. This command will delete all new ipcs that your program creates.

Comment: Yes ipcrm -a does the job, I shoud'v a least  used IPC_EXCL to prevent this problem from happening or free the semaphore and the shared memory for a correct code! Thank you